# Apache poi exception: Invalid header signature; read 0x0010000200040009

Tags: apache-poi, xls, apache-tika

I'm getting the following error:

```
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x0010000200040009, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:144)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:113)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:231)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:167)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:254)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:226)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:205)
at main.Raport.read_excels(Raport.java:261)
at main.Raport.<init>(Raport.java:67)
at main.Avanzamento$4.actionPerformed(Avanzamento.java:138)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

In this part of my code:

```
wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file_excel);
```

My file IS AN EXCEL FILE. i have checked also with TIKA (1.18):
and it gives that my file is:

```
application/vnd.ms-excel
```

I can't figure out where is the problem....
All is fine if I open the doc in Excel and save it again with the current format (.xls)

**EDIT:**
i'm doing something like this to read with TIKA:

```
package main;

import java.io.File;

import org.apache.tika.Tika;

public class Detect_type {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

          File file = new File("C:/Users/EDP/Desktop/conf 1/2018/201812.xls");

          //Instantiating tika facade class 
          Tika tika = new Tika();

          //detecting the file type using detect method
          String filetype = tika.detect(file);
          System.out.println(filetype);
       }
```

}

**EDIT 2**
now i'm passing the path to the file without ".xls" extension:

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/EDP/Desktop/conf 1/2018/201812");
```

and also in Windows i removed the extension:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykiLe.png)

And getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\EDP\Desktop\conf 1\2018\201812 (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.apache.tika.io.TikaInputStream.<init>(TikaInputStream.java:496)
    at org.apache.tika.io.TikaInputStream.get(TikaInputStream.java:267)
    at org.apache.tika.Tika.detect(Tika.java:287)
    at main.Detect_type.main(Detect_type.java:17)
```

Comment: Try doing the Tika detect without passing in the filename (eg `java -jar tika-app.jar --detect < input.xls`) and see what that says. Also, what version of Apache POI are you trying?

Comment: i'm using 3.17 version

Comment: OK, and what does Tika say the type is if you hide the filename?

Comment: please check my EDIT answer

Comment: Just try with the single-jar Tika app and piping the contents in, or rename your file to have no file extension and pass that into your code, and see what Tika detects when there's no filename hint

Comment: the result is: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\EDP\Desktop\conf 1\2018\201812 (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: If you've given Tika the wrong path then not a lot it can do to help... Pass in the correct file (but without the filename / renamed to no extension)

Comment: @Gagravarr please check my EDIT 2. sorry if i don't understand you....

Comment: You can't just leave off the extension if passing a file object! You either need to rename the file to not have the extension, or use the Tika app and pipe the contents in so there's no filename known